# Definite articles preceding people’s first names?

Tags: gramática, artículos

I have heard some Spanish speakers use a definite article before a person’s first name, e.g., “la Maria”. Based on my research, this is colloquial and is used in cases where the speaker feels close to the person they are referring to.

I would like to know in which parts of the Spanish-speaking world this is used and whether it is used equally for masculine and feminine first names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La María, la Señora María, el Manolo, el Señor Manuel, el Julián, la Rosario... esta manera de hablar para referirse a ciertas personas en España son típicas de Cataluña, especialmente los pueblos y ciudades que rodean Barcelona y en algunos barrios de algunas ciudades del Sur de España. En este último caso los nombres habituales se mezclan con los apodos o con ciertas características del personaje, la Malhambre, la Pololos, la Tanga, el Tomate, el Curry... (Igualmente, es común oírlo y nombrar así a ciertos toreros).

Ciertamente es una forma coloquial, aunque en algunos casos bastante extendida, sin embargo, ello no significa que la persona tenga que tener un especial vinculo con el así llamado, es solo la manera de nombrarlo. En ocasiones puede existir ese vinculo más cercano que comenta, pero en otras es inexistente. Fuera de estos contextos específicos, no se considera plausible esa manera de dirigirse o hablar de alguien.

Comment: Seguramente por la procedencia  de esas regiones de España, en el norte argentino se estila esa manera de aludir a los nombres proios, apodos e incluso relaciones ("la Mariela", "el Mocho", "la tía Eugenia")

Comment: Antiguamente, en las antiguas corralas, viviendas grandes con un patio central, donde solían vivir muchos vecinos, de distintos lugares, incluida Madrid, era costumbre extendida, (ej.la seña Matilde pregunto por usted..la señora Matilde pregunto por usted..la Matilde) costumbre que paulatinamente con el desarrollo de los nuevos tiempos se fue perdiendo, focalizándose actualmente en unos pocos lugares. Es posible que antiguamente en Argentina se diera ese mismo tipo de convivencia con aquellas mismas costumbres, de ahí la aparente cercanía y trato que comentas y que en un principio si fue real.

Comment: En Catalán los nombres propios deben ir precedidos por el correspondiente artículo definido (En/Na,  El/La). Esta influencia del Catalán hace que en algunas partes de Cataluña la gente use estos artículos definidos al hablar en Castellano.

Answer (score 1):

Preceding the article before an anthroponym is correct when it has a generalizing function:

> *No es el Juan que conocí.*
> (It's not the John I know.)

In the rest of the cases it is usually regarded as vulgar, except for speakers from Chile or Catalonia (and maybe in other places), where it can also be found in the formal register.

Also, although less frequent, it is used with some female personalities (usually before their surname): *la Callas*, *la Thatcher*.

Comment: How is it regarded as vulgar but found in formal registers?

Comment: @hb20007 I've clarified the answer.